# How can I guarantee that audio only from my media player hits the speakers?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, audio, mediaplayer

I'm DJ-ing and I want to make sure that my music and nothing else is getting pumped out the speakers.

Undesirable things that may hit the speakers include:

- Calendar.app reminders
- Messages.app alerts
- Calls (e.g. via FaceTime or Continuity)
- Media playing in other applications, such as YouTube in my browser
- System sounds (such as when you change the volume)

Of course, many of these things can be mitigated by turning WiFi off or fiddling with settings here and there. But it would be better if there was an explicit way to somehow specify that only audio from my media player gets to the speakers.

Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Comment: This may be possible to do with software like [Loopback](https://rogueamoeba.com/loopback/) which lets you create virtual audio devices and map audio to and from them.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of an explicit way (I doubt there is one), but ClickToFlash and Do Not Disturb mode (Option click the notification center icon to toggle) will cover most of those things.

To disable the volume "popping" sound effect: open **System Preferences > Sound > Sound Effects** tab, and uncheck **play feedback when sound is changed**

Answer (score 2):

I would do two things:

1. In System Preferences > Notifications, select Do Not Disturb and ensure that "Allow FaceTime calls from:" and "Allow repeated calls" are both unchecked. Then turn on Do Not Disturb by opening Notification Center, swiping down, and toggling the switch
2. In System Preferences > Sound, uncheck "Play user interface sound effects" and "Play feedback when volume is changed." Drag the Alert Volume slider all the way to the left

Answer (score 2):

To some degree you can separate the system sounds from audio.

I would use the Audio Midi (located in your utility folder) and set it up to have all system sounds go to build in speakers wile other sounds go to external speakers.

Something like this:

The icons indicate which sound goes where.

[image: midi]